# marquee data pass

Tags: android, marquee

Can you help me in how we can create a marquee for news , but I need that every news be clickable to show the detail page of the selected news.

I know we have many of examples considering marquee but no one was clickable for every item in the marquee. Here is some code I m trying but its not giving individual news text in next activity.

Please help me

```
 t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);
    t.setSelected(true);
    t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // in.putExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE", t.getText().toString());
            Intent in = new Intent(mContext, News.class);
            in.putExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE", t.getText().toString());
            mContext.startActivity(in);


        }
    });
```

this is marquee built

```
 for (int i = 0; i < offerlist.length(); i++) {

                        url.add(offerlist.getJSONObject(i).getString("url"));
                        t.setText( offerlist.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));

                    }

                    t.setSelected(true);
```

i am trying to create bundle but its giving error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read value stored in Bundle with key "**EdiTtEXTvALUE**", use this:

```
if (getIntent() != null) {
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE") {
        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE");
    }
}
```

Be careful not to pass values, that exceeds the maximum size for Intent - **1MB**

Comment: My problem is when I clicj on one text in marquee and move to other activity . It is pqssing whole text of marquee to other activity. What I want is one text only . The one I clicked